# How to design a table header in Xcode's IB in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode using Swift, I would add a header, UITableViewHeaderFooterView, to a table, UITableView.
I would design it in IB and then use dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView, but any attempt failed for various reasons.
Have I to add a UIView in the main Storyboard, or prepare a new dedicated storyboard, or a xib file?
How to connect it to the Swift code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new xib file, design the header view in that file, and then call [`register(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614921-register) when you set up the table view.

Something like this:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "FileNameOfYourXIBFile", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "myHeader")
```

And then you can do:

```
let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "myHeader")
```

Comment: Thanks Sweeper. The IB create .storyboard or .xib file. With the xib file enveloping one View with a label, The code aborted because "invalid nib registered for identifier (myHeader) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewHeaderFooterView instance".

Comment: @Luca_65 You should do exactly what the error says. You should not use a plain old `UIView` in the xib. Change the "Class" of the view in the identity inspector to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In IB, <header>.xib file, I set the view custom class to my implementation of  **UITableViewHeaderFooterView**, which currently is empty.
The View in IB have a label, which isn't displayed.

Comment: @Luca_65 That's weird. Did you include the extension ".xib" in `FileNameOfYourXIBFile`? You should not do that.

Comment: I use the bare name only
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
  super.viewDidLoad()
                tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Header", bundle: nil),forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "myHeader")
    }

Comment: @Luca_65 Oh wait, so now you are saying that the error message is gone, but the label is not displayed? Maybe try overriding `heightForHeaderInSection` and return some positive number?